# Responsive css not working on landscape

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm implementing a responsive website, and even though it's working
on tablets and smartphones on normal orientation, but when I flip it to
horizontal the design gets jumbled, also, on the normal orientation
when I manually re-size the website the footer rides up, and it's
supposed to stay on the bottom.

I have been trying for a few days, let me know if you've had similar problems.

My code:

```
 <body>
        <!--Header-->
            <div class="header_container">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="#" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor" align="center"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>
<!--Content-->
        <div class="content_container">
                <div class="middle">
                    <div class="middle-item">
                        <div class="loading">
                            <img src="./img/icon/ajax-loader.gif" align="center" />
                        </div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt.</p>
                        <p class="small">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        <a class="btn-play-grey" href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#"/></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
<!--Footer section-->
        <div class="footer_container">
                <div class="link_footer">

                        <span class="copyright">All Content Copyright @ Lorem Ipsum Co., Ltd.  |  Find us on   </span><a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="./img/icon/instagram.png"/></a>

                </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

/* CSS
    ================================================== */

```
* { 
    margin: 0;  
    padding: 0;
    list-style:none;
}

html,
body { height: 100%; }

/* Body 
================================================== */
body {
    background: url('../img/bg/large/intro.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.25;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: relative;
    min-height:100%;
}

/* Header
================================================== */
.header_container {
    position: relative;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    padding: 21px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.logo {
    width: 181px;
    height: 33px;
    padding-left: 105px;
}

/* Content
================================================== */
.content_container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    zoom: 1;
}

.content_container .middle{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.content_container .middle .middle-item p {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #70cbd1;
    padding-top: 70px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.content_container .middle .middle-item .small {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}

.content_container .middle .middle-item .btn-play-grey img{
    height: 65px;
    width: 201px;
}

/* Footer
================================================== */
.footer_container {
    background: #e5e5e5;
    width: 100%;
    bottom:0;
    height: 70px;
    position: absolute;
}

.footer_container .link_footer {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-right: 105px;
    padding-top: 23px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: right;
    clear:both;
}

.footer_container .link_footer img {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 24px auto;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (orientation : landscape){

    html, body {
        /*        height: auto;*/
        background-image: url('../img/bg/small/intro.jpg');
    }

    .logo {

        padding-left: 25px;
    }

    .footer_container .link_footer {
        padding-right: 0;
        text-align: center;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide example what do you see on the screen? Can you make a minimal html and css that reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this meta tag to you head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thanks Kamil. I was using <meta name="viewport" content="width=768"> and I removed and added that to the head but it seemed not to make any difference. I think the problem is in the content and footer... Do have any other ideas?